# Angular4 file upload PUT request fails

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, http-put, angular-httpclient

Angular4 file upload to PUT method fails but for POST it works fine. Any one having idea what's going on here??

**HTML**

```
<input #fileSelect type="file" class="form-control" (change)="onFileUpload($event)"  accept=".jpg, .png"/>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
   imageToUpload: any;
    @ViewChild('fileSelect') fileSelectInput: ElementRef;

    onFileUpload(event) {
        this.imageToUpload = event.srcElement.files;
      }

    uploadImage() {
      let formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', this.imageToUpload[0]);

    this.http.post(this.apiUrl, formData, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe((imageId) => {
          // response
        });
    }

// fails with 400 bad request
    updateImage(formData: FormData, imageId: string) {    
        this.http.put(`${this.apiUrl}/${imageId}`, formData).subscribe((response) => {
          // response
        });
      }
```

For POST no issues, files are uploading perfectly. But for PUT getting 400 Bad Request error. Any idea what's going on? I'm scratching my head from last 2 days. Any help would be really appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Did you double check that your webserver allows the PUT method?

Comment: yes, when I use the PUT method with POSTMAN everything works fine.

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: I'm using spring boot back-end with embedded tomcat.

Comment: Refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830945/angular-2-template-form-with-input-type-file-and-spring-boot/46909023#46909023

Comment: @hrdkisback thanks for the comment. My question was not on how to file upload using angular and spring boot. File upload is failing for PUT but works perfectly with POST not sure what's the reason.

Comment: Using chrome's debugger, can you actually see which header and if the file is sent? This is to make sure  that it's the same data as when using postman

Comment: Try by adding `headers`.