# angular 7 & spring boot 2 file upload problem

Tags: java, angular, spring, upload

fileUpload.html

```
    <p-fileUpload name="file" customUpload="true" (uploadHandler)="myUploader($event)"
 type="file" accept=".lsx, .xlsx" [auto]="true" ></p-fileUpload>
```

fileUpload.ts

```
    myUploader(event):void{

        const formdata:FormData = new FormData();
        const fileToUpload: File = event.files[0];

        formdata.append('file', fileToUpload);

        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8081/fileUpload', formdata);

       this.httpClient.request(req).subscribe(); 
}
```

fileUpload.java

```
   @PostMapping(value = "/fileUpload")
    public ApiResponse giftCardBatchList(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        fileUploadService.upload(file);
        return new ApiResponse(ApiResponseStatus.SUCCESS, null);
    }
```

controller doesn't catch the request and I got this exception

> MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is
>   not present

if I change

> @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file

to

> @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] file

controller catches the request but the file array contains nothing. It is empty :(

any ideas?

thank you guys !

Comment: Try this way `@RequestParam MultipartFile file` and let me know.

Comment: got same exception "Required request part 'file' is not present" :(

Comment: Try to pass content type in headers with request, like this .`new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8081/fileUpload', formData, {headers: headers});` refer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279484/sending-file-object-to-spring-rest-controller-through-angular-5/48295301#48295301

Comment: I did exactly the same request with same headers but got the same exception :(

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your annotation as like below,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/fileUpload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ApiResponse giftCardBatchList(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {
        fileUploadService.upload(file);
        return new ApiResponse(ApiResponseStatus.SUCCESS, null);
    }
```

Comment: didn't work :( get same exception Required request part 'file' is not present

Comment: can you check your request payload whether file is getting submitted ?

Comment: add this in your application.properties,

`# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB`

Comment: didnt help these properties :(

Answer (score 0):

Try modfying in ts file as below before calling post api

const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

```
formdata.append("file",fil[0]);
```

or 
    formdata.set("file",fil[0]);

Comment: after these changes I got same exception :(